# using daypilot in vb.net website

Tags: vb.net, linq, calendar, timetable, daypilot

I have downloaded the lite version of `DayPilot` from `http://www.daypilot.org/daypilot-lite.html`  I have started working with it to try and get it going.  I have a website already built which I intend on linking this into.  The site is vb.net and I am using linq to sql.  Has anyone used this calendar before?  I am not sure of how to use it.  I have created the control on my sidebar and can drag it into the page no problem.  The issue is that on the website there are tutorials which I have started working on.  However when I use the code from the tutorials the controls are not recognised. It is as though I need to add more files to my website for controls to work.  I am not very experienced with aftermarket controls, or coding for that matter.  For example I have copied the following code:

```
Protected Sub DayPilotCalendar1_EventMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events.EventMoveEventArgs) Handles DayPilotCalendar1.EventMove
    dbUpdateEvent(e.Value, e.NewStart, e.NewEnd)
    DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = dbGetEvents(DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate, DayPilotCalendar1.Days)
    DayPilotCalendar1.DataBind()
    DayPilotCalendar1.Update()
End Sub
```

The lines `DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events.EventMoveEventArgs)` and `DayPilotCalendar1.Update()` come up with the error "Type DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events.EventMoveEventArgs is not defined" and "Update is not a member of DayPilot.Web.UI.DayPilotCalendar".   Any tips or advice.  Btw I don't feel skilled enough to create my own timetable, unless somebody knows of a fairly comprehensive guide of how to do it.

Comment: Did you add a reference to DayPilot in your URL? If you have, then I predict you are missing the import statements, e.g:
Imports DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events & Imports DayPilot - these need to go to the very top of your page.

Comment: Hi Butters.  Yes I have referenced it in my url with <%@ Register `Assembly="DayPilot" Namespace="DayPilot.Web.Ui" TagPrefix="DayPilot" %>`  I tried the imports as suggested but they have not had any effect

Answer (score 0):

DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events.EventMoveEventArgs is not available in DayPilot Lite for ASP.NET WebForms (EventMove event is not supported).

You need to switch to the **Pro** version (paid):
http://www.daypilot.org/try.html

or use DayPilot Lite for ASP.NET **MVC** (open-source):
http://mvc.daypilot.org/lite/